# How to use "more likely"

Tags: word-usage

Is it only valid to use "more likely" as in "Polar bears are more likely to be found in cold places" or could you also say "Polar bears are more likely found in cold places"?

Can you use "more likely" with an adjective? So e.g. "Bodybuilders are more likely to be healthy persons" or "Bodybuilders are more likely healthy persons"?

Regarding incline is it correct to say "Rich people are more likely inclined to donate more money" or would you say "Rich people are more likely to be inclined to donate more money"?

3 questions at once, but I think they're so closely related that it is ok...

Comment: All are okay, but "more likely inclined" sounds funny. "tend to be more inclined" sounds better. I don 't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All are okay.  The shorter versions are a bit formal or old fashioned in flavor.